# Custom template for content type, How to print a link field as a hyperlinked image

Tags: entities, nodes

I am making a site for a music festival. I have one content type for attending artists, which includes the following fields of the fields type Link: soundcloud, youtube etc.

I would like to print these fields with an image (small icons) instead of the written link.

How can I do that?

( The path I am looking at for the moment: copy node.tpl.php, rename to node--artist.tpl.php, add some code, put in sites/all/themes/default_theme. )

Comment: Found an interesting tutorial: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and more practical apply a preproccess hook:

```
Function YOUR_THEME_proprocces_node__artist(&$vars){

 // $vars contain the fields to be renderable in content attribute

}
```

I resolved a similar question a few days ago: [change links read more and add comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71212/how-to-change-read-more-and-add-new-comment-link-to-an-image-in-teaser-view/71279#71279)

Inside of array tree `$vars['content]`, you will have to change the title attribute adding the html mark you want.

If you have a problem to find the tree or change the array, print the array with the `dpm($vars)` in your code and capture an screenshot to publish here.

Comment: Thanks! I am not quite with you though .. 
Where shall I put the preprocess-function? I am using Corolla as default theme (sub-theme to Adaptive theme).

Comment: IN the _template.php_ file in your sub-theme